# Spring Boot Unit Testing with WebMvcTest + JWT + AuthenticationPrinciple

Tags: spring-boot, unit-testing, spring-security

I have a project with Spring-Boot + Spring-Security. In this project, typical I have MVC architecture.

My controller looks like:

```
@RestController
DemoController
{
    public ResponseEntity<?> get(@AuthenticationPrinciple UserPrinciple userPrinciple)
    { 
       return ...
    }
}
```

I want to test this controller class with WebMvcTest. I know that I can handle it with SpringBootTest easily but SpringBootTest is not time-effective...

I've created a test class like:

```
@WebMvcTest(controllers = {DemoController.class})
DemoControllerTest
{
    @Autowired
    private MockMvc mockMvc;

    @Test
    void test_get()
    {
        this.mockMvc.perform(get("/...")
                .header(AUTH_HEADER, getAuthorizationHeader())
            .andExpect(status().isOk());
    }
}
```

But I got error like userPrinciple is null or `org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type 'com.sha.springbootbookseller.security.CustomUserDetailsService' available: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate.` How I can inject  AuthenticationPrinciple in WebMvcTest?

Example Code: https://github.com/senolatac/spring-boot-book-seller

Test Class: https://github.com/senolatac/spring-boot-book-seller/blob/master/src/test/java/com/sha/springbootbookseller/controller/PurchaseHistoryControllerTest.java

Comment: Did you try adding `@Import(YourSecurityConfiguration.class)` on your `DemoControllerTest` class?

Comment: @MarcusHertdaCoregio tried but same

Comment: It's hard to tell without knowing your whole configuration. Are you using `oauth2ResourceServer`?

Comment: This is the code: https://github.com/senolatac/spring-boot-book-seller

Comment: i looked at your code @Sha and it looks like you have read a lot of outdated and uninformed blogposts. Spring security has full JWT support so why you have written a lot of custom filters etc is not needed and bad practice. Spring security is a security framework, it already has all that built in. Why use a security framework, when you dont use it at all

Comment: @Toerktumlare thanks for your review. Do you have references/resources for best-practices?

Comment: Just read the spring security documentation chapter on jwts

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved it with adding:

```
@WithMockUser
@ContextConfiguration
```

and mocking

```
@MockBean
private CustomUserDetailsService customUserDetailsService;
```

Final result looks like:

```
@WithMockUser
@WebMvcTest(controllers = {DemoController.class})
@ContextConfiguration(classes = {DemoController.class, JwtProvider.class, JwtFilter.class})
DemoControllerTest
{
    @Autowired
    private MockMvc mockMvc;

    @MockBean
    private CustomUserDetailsService customUserDetailsService;

    @Test
    void test_get()
    {
        this.mockMvc.perform(get("/...")
                .header(AUTH_HEADER, getAuthorizationHeader())
            .andExpect(status().isOk());
    }
}
```

you can find the example code from: https://github.com/senolatac/spring-boot-book-seller